# Model View Controller Dynamic embedding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Problem Statement: I need to have two controllers: Client Controller and Server Controller. The Server Controller will render the model and the static view(JSP) to the client controller. The client controller will process the model and dynamically embed the model attributes in the view and finally, the client Controller will render the final updated view to the client. Is this possible to be implemented using Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple controllers in Spring MVC. In fact it is one of the advantages of using Spring MVC. 
`@RequestMapping` annotation for the classes. The value of that annotation will be the prefix of all requests coming to that controller.

For example:

Controller 1

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("client")
public class ClientController {

@RequestMapping("link") //same value
public ModelAndView edit()
}
```

Controller 2

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("server")
public class ClientController {

@RequestMapping("link") //same value
public ModelAndView edit()
}
```

Comment: Here how the Controller 2 is redirecting the ModelAndView instance to Controller 1 that is Client Controller?